# PostgreSQL 9.6: How to sum all attributes in a nested jsonb?

Tags: json, postgresql, nested, sum

I am working with PostgreSQL 9.6.

If sum all attributes in a 1 level jsonb, we can do below:

```
drop table if exists tmp;
create table tmp(id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, data jsonb);
insert into tmp(data) values
('{"a":100,"b":200,"c":300}'),('{"a":10,"b":20,"c":30}'),('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}');
select jsonb_object_agg(key, sum)
from
(
    select key, sum(value::int)
    from tmp 
    cross join jsonb_each_text(data)
    group by key
) tmp_each;
```

result:

```
{"a":111,"b":222,"c":333}
```

But if the jsonb filed with a nested jsonb more than 1 level like below:

```
insert into tmp(data) values
('{
  "a": {
    "a1": 110,
    "a2": 120,
    "a3": 130,
    "a4": {
      "a41": 141,
      "a42": 142,
      "a43": 143,
      "a44": 144,
      "a45": 145
    }
  },
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300
}'),
('{
  "a": {
    "a1": 1110,
    "a2": 1120,
    "a3": 1130,
    "a4": {
      "a41": 1141,
      "a42": 1142,      
      "a45": 1145
    }
  },
  "b": 1200,
  "c": 1300
}'),
('{
  "a": {
    "a1": 110,
    "a2": 120,
    "a3": 130,
    "a4": {      
      "a42": 142,
      "a43": 143,
      "a44": 144
    }
  },
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300
}');
```

I can use jsonb_deep_sum extension easily:

https://github.com/furstenheim/jsonb_deep_sum

```
SELECT jsonb_deep_sum(data) FROM tmp;
```

result:

```
{
  "a": {
    "a1": 1330,
    "a2": 1360,
    "a3": 1390,
    "a4": {
      "a41": 1282,
      "a42": 1426,
      "a43": 286,
      "a44": 288,
      "a45": 1290
    }
  },
  "b": 1600,
  "c": 1900
}
```

But if I want to use SQL without using jsonb_deep_sum extension, how to finish the SQL?

Thank you very much for reviewing my question.

Answer (score 0):

answering here, but it is more of a long comment rather and an answer.

If there is a way to do it without the extension, most probably the way to do it is first to explode the json into paths and values, and then aggregate.

In the case that you have more structure into your jsonb, then it is possible. For example, if you always know that key `a` will be either not present or present with an object structure and so on. But most probably will be a PITA. You can check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540444/insert-new-item-in-jsonb-column-based-on-value-of-other-field-postgres/64544288#64544288), it is not exactly summing, but there is a complex aggregation. In that case the structure was known, which made it `easier`, but really cumbersome. Basically, you do a jsonb_each and then for the properties that are objects, you do it again.

If you don't have a common structure. Then, you need to find a way to explode the jsonb first. Something like a recursive version of jsonb_each. Then you would do the summation aggregation, and then another aggregation using jsonb_set.

If you find the way to do it, I would be interested in it to write the benchmark on the `jsonb_deep_sum` extension for 1 nested level.