# Insert new item in JSONB column based on value of other field - postgres

Tags: postgresql, flyway, jsonb

I have the following jsonb structure with many entries in it

```
[
   {
      "name":"test",
      "features":[
         {
            "name":"feature1",
            "granted":false
         },
         {
            "name":"feature2",
            "granted":true
         }
      ]
   }...
]
```

I'd like to add a new entry in the `features` array when the parent `name` element has value "test" and `feature1` `granted` is "false".

The idea is to write a flyway script to migrate my data.
I've been battling with `jsonb_insert` but I can't figure out the path portion of it since I can have potentially many elements in there and I can't just add a given subscript.

End result should be:

```
[
   {
      "name":"test",
      "features":[
         {
            "name":"feature1",
            "granted":false
         },
         {
            "name":"feature2",
            "granted":true
         },
         {
            "name":"newFeature",
            "granted":false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**EDIT1**

So far I've attempted:

```
UPDATE my_table SET modules =
    jsonb_insert(my_column, '{features, [0]}', '{"name": "newFeature", "granted": false}')
WHERE my_column ->> 'name' = 'test' AND my_column @> '{"features": [{"name":"feature1", "granted": false}]}';
```

The statement executes but no updates are actually done.

**EDIT2**

I modified the query just to test the PATH out to

```
UPDATE my_table SET modules =
    jsonb_insert(my_column, '{0, features, 0}', '{"name": "newFeature", "granted": false}')
WHERE my_column ->> 'name' = 'test' AND my_column @> '{"features": [{"name":"feature1", "granted": false}]}';
```

However this only always updates the first entry in the array, and the object I need to update is not guaranteed to always be in this position

Comment: The jsonb_insert is wrong, right? You are not inserting into a features key, but features is an element of an array. So at least it would be jsonb_insert( '{[0], features, [0]}')

In my experience, for really big and complicated jsons, you might be well off doing it in app code instead of sql, if you can sacrifice transactionality.

If you cannot do that, try exploding the json to get a row for each of the elements that you are interested.

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim the jsonb_insert is wrong right now yes. I did try with adding {0, features, 0} but the problem there is that I cannot guarantee that the element I'm looking for will be in the first position. it may be situated anywhere in the array

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim Do you mind sharing an example of how I can explode the json per row  in an sql statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name had originally posted a solution for just an object but I failed to mention it was an array of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough information to complete the query:

Let's create the mock data

```
create table a (id serial primary key , b jsonb);

insert into a (b)
values ('[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "features": [
      {
        "name": "feature1",
        "granted": false
      },
      {
        "name": "feature2",
        "granted": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "another-name",
    "features": [
      {
        "name": "feature1",
        "granted": false
      },
      {
        "name": "feature2",
        "granted": true
      }
    ]
  }
]');
```

Now explode the array using jsonb_array_elements with ordinality to get the index and the property

```
select first_level.id, position, feature_position, feature
from (select a.id, arr.*
      from a,
           jsonb_array_elements(a.b) with ordinality arr (elem, position)
      where elem ->> 'name' = 'test') first_level,
     jsonb_array_elements(first_level.elem -> 'features') with ordinality features (feature, feature_position);
```

The result of this query is:

```
1,1,1,"{""name"": ""feature1"", ""granted"": false}"
1,1,2,"{""name"": ""feature2"", ""granted"": true}"
```

There you have the necessary info that you need to fetch the sub elements that you need, as well as all the indexes that you needed for your query.

Now, to the final edit, you already had the query that you wanted:

```
UPDATE my_table SET modules =
    jsonb_insert(my_column, '{0, features, 0}', '{"name": "newFeature", "granted": false}')
WHERE my_column ->> 'name' = 'test' AND my_column @> '{"features": [{"name":"feature1", "granted": false}]}';
```

In the where you'll use the id, because those are the rows that you are interested in, and in the indexes you got them from the query. So:

```
UPDATE my_table SET modules =
    jsonb_insert(my_column, '{' || exploded_info.position::string || ', features, ' || exploded_info.feature_position || '}', '{"name": "newFeature", "granted": false}') from (/* previous query */) as exploded_info
WHERE exploded_info.id = my_table.id and exploded_info.feature -> 'granted' = false;
```

As you can see this easily get's very nasty.

I'd recommend either using a more sql approach, that is, having features in a table instead of inside a json, a fk linking that to your table...
If you really need to use the json, for example, because the domain is really complex and defined at the application level and very flexible. Then I would recommend doing the updates inside app code

Comment: This is very helpful but I still need to run an update on the main table itself, i don't see how i can connect this query with the UPDATE which is my ultimate goal.

Comment: @VenelinK I've expanded the answer a little bit more